# AttributeError in Python regarding classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter

DEFAULT_FONT = 'Helvetica, 16'


class UserInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self._root_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self._canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master=self._root_window,
                                      width=400,
                                      height=400,
                                      background='#2A722E')

        self._canvas.grid(row=0,
                          column=0,
                          padx=30,
                          pady=30,
                          sticky=tkinter.W + tkinter.E + tkinter.N + tkinter.S)

        self._ask_user_input()

    def run(self):
        self._root_window.mainloop()

    def _ask_user_input(self):
        user_input = UserInput()
        user_input.show()

        if user_input.ok_is_clicked():
            input_list = user_input.get_input_list()
            return input_list


class UserInput:
    def __init__(self):
        self._user_input = tkinter.Toplevel()

        row_num = tkinter.Label(master=self._user_input,
                                text='Specify a row number 4-16:',
                                font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        row_num.grid(row=0,
                     column=0,
                     padx=10,
                     pady=10,
                     sticky=tkinter.W)

        self._row_num_entry = tkinter.Entry(master=self._user_input,
                                            width=15,
                                            font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        self._row_num_entry.grid(row=0,
                                 column=1,
                                 padx=10,
                                 pady=10,
                                 sticky=tkinter.E)

        col_num = tkinter.Label(master=self._user_input,
                                text='Specify a column number 4-16:',
                                font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        col_num.grid(row=1,
                     column=0,
                     padx=10,
                     pady=10,
                     sticky=tkinter.W)

        self._col_num_entry = tkinter.Entry(master=self._user_input,
                                            width=15,
                                            font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        self._col_num_entry.grid(row=1,
                                 column=1,
                                 padx=10,
                                 pady=10, sticky=tkinter.E)

        first_player = tkinter.Label(master=self._user_input,
                                     text='Specify the first player B/W:',
                                     font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        first_player.grid(row=2,
                          column=0,
                          padx=10,
                          pady=10,
                          sticky=tkinter.W)

        self._first_player_entry = tkinter.Entry(master=self._user_input,
                                                 width=15,
                                                 font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        self._first_player_entry.grid(row=2,
                                      column=1,
                                      padx=10,
                                      pady=10,
                                      sticky=tkinter.W)

        win_condition = tkinter.Label(master=self._user_input,
                                      text='Specify a winning condition, < or >:',
                                      font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        win_condition.grid(row=3,
                           column=0,
                           padx=10,
                           pady=10,
                           sticky=tkinter.W)

        self._win_condition_entry = tkinter.Entry(master=self._user_input,
                                                  width=15,
                                                  font=DEFAULT_FONT)
        self._win_condition_entry.grid(row=3,
                                       column=1,
                                       padx=10,
                                       pady=10,
                                       sticky=tkinter.E)

        ok_button = tkinter.Button(master=self._user_input,
                                   text='OK',
                                   font=DEFAULT_FONT,
                                   command=self._ok_button_clicked)
        ok_button.grid(row=4,
                       columnspan=2,
                       padx=40,
                       pady=40)

        self._ok_clicked = False
        self._input_list = []

    def show(self) -> None:
        self._user_input.grab_set()
        self._user_input.wait_window()

    def ok_is_clicked(self) -> bool:
        return self._ok_clicked

    def _ok_button_clicked(self):
        self._ok_clicked = True

        row_num = self._row_num_entry.get()
        col_num = self._col_num_entry.get()
        starter = self._first_player_entry.get()
        winning = self._win_condition_entry.get()

        self._input_list.extend([row_num, col_num, starter, winning])

        self._user_input.destroy()

    def get_input_list(self) -> list:
        return self._input_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = UserInterface()
    game.run()
```

However when I run the UserInteface() class by assigning it to a variable, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cagataycakiroglu/Desktop/othello_gui.py", line 166, in <module>
    game = UserInterface()
  File "/Users/cagataycakiroglu/Desktop/othello_gui.py", line 26, in __init__
    user_input = self._ask_user_input()
  File "/Users/cagataycakiroglu/Desktop/othello_gui.py", line 36, in _ask_user_input
    user_input = UserInput()
  File "/Users/cagataycakiroglu/Desktop/othello_gui.py", line 127, in __init__
    command = self._ok_button_clicked)
AttributeError: 'UserInput' object has no attribute '_ok_button_clicked'
```

What am I doing wrong? Please explain as you'd explain to a Python novice without using advanced techniques like lambda or so. Thanks!

Comment: You need to fix your indentation and fill in the code for `__init__` in `UserInput` so we can actually see the code going wrong. Also, you seem to have omitted the open paren when calling `self._ok_button_clicked()` (you have `self._ok_button_clicked)`).

Comment: Can you take a look now? Also, aren't commands supposed to not have parantheses?

Comment: You are missing the reference to self in init's signature.

Comment: @pycoder: Ah, in this case, no, no parens needed. They were passing it as a callback function, not calling it directly, so the original code was correct there. The traceback didn't have the context to make it clear it was passing the method as a callback function.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are right. I didn't looking at the code, just responding to the question about methods.

Comment: What is `DEFAULT_FONT`?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for not adding it. Just edited.

Comment: I do not get any errors when I run your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing self in `__init__()`. It should read:

```
def __init__(self):
```

I don't know if that is your only problem because you didn't post all of the code (the snippet you gave won't run for many other reasons), but I am assuming that this is what you were looking for.

#### Edit

```
self._dialog_window.destroy()
```

No definition for `_dialog_window` exists.

#### Edit 2

```
command = self._ok_button_clicked())
```

Should read:

```
command = self._ok_button_clicked)
```

Lists don't have a destroy method:

```
self._input_list.destroy()  # this will fail
```

Comment: @CagatayCakiroglu Ideally, you should strip as much code as possible from your example, so you end up with minimal example that: a) can be run by others; b) still shows the problem; c) doesn't include anything that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Don't infringe someone's intellectual property rights when you post your code.

Comment: I edited both. Still error. (I forgot deleting the parentheses after the previous suggestion failed. The list one should have been self._user_input.destroy() Sorry for the mistake...